# Declare and initialize unique_ptr inside a structure

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I was wondering how I can declare a unique ptr inside a structure and initialize it later. Right now I have

```
struct CacheObject {
    std::string _cache_type; 
    std::unique_ptr<faiss::Cache> cache; 

    uint64_t _cache_size;
    // Real time data 
    int64_t rt_byte_req;
    int64_t rt_byte_miss;
    int64_t rt_obj_req;
    int64_t rt_obj_miss;

    CacheObject();
};
```

and

```
CacheObject::CacheObject() : _cache_type("LRU"), cache(nullptr),
        _cache_size(5000), rt_byte_req(0), rt_byte_miss(0),
        rt_obj_req(0), rt_obj_miss(0) {}
```

But I got an error message saying that

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = faiss::Cache; _Dp = std::default_delete<faiss::Cache>]’
       arg2 = *temp;
```

Why would this happen and how can I revise it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`std::unique_ptr` can't be copied, only moved, so the compiler can't generate a copy assignment `operator=` for your struct. Thus, a statement like `arg2 = *temp;`, where `arg2` and `*temp` are `CacheObject` objects, will not work by default.

You will need to implement your own copy assignment `operator=` to clone the `faiss::Cache` object, eg:

```cpp
struct CacheObject {
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<faiss::Cache> cache; 
    ...

    CacheObject& operator=(const CacheObject &rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
        {
            if (rhs.cache)
                cache.reset(new faiss::Cache(*(rhs.cache))); // or equivalent...
            else
                cache.reset();

            // copy other members as needed...
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

...

arg2 = *temp;
```

And/or, implement a move assignment `operator=` to move the `unique_ptr` from one `CacheObject` to another, eg:

```cpp
struct CacheObject {
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<faiss::Cache> cache; 
    ...

    CacheObject& operator=(CacheObject &&rhs)
    {
        cache = std::move(rhs.cache);
        // move other members as needed...
        return *this;
    }
};

...

arg2 = std::move(*temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a amendment to what @remylebeau has already mentioned.  The `std::unique_ptr<>` does have the `reset()` member function as well.  You could something like this too

```
struct  CacheObject {
    // ....
    void SetCacheObject(faiss::Cache* p)
    {
        if (p) {
            // This assumes you're resetting it because you no longer
            // care about what it pointed to
            delete cache.release();
        }
        cache.reset(p);
    }
};



void SomeFunc()
{
    CacheObject co;
    // ... elsewhere and after important stuff
    co.SetCacheObject(new faiss::Cache());
}
```

You can reference [this link for reset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) and [this link for release](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release).

### Edit

After doing some thinking, I think it important to mention that if you should use this approach **and** the `std::unique_ptr<faiss::Cache>` object has a valid reference, you're going to leak memory unless you properly handle it.  I've changed the code example with *one possible way* of preventing this.